# ant Sending email using does not work, without any error message

Tags: email, ant

I'm using this ant script in order to send email:

```
<target name="install-jars" description="Install ANT optional jars">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib" />
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/mail.jar"
        src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/mail/mail/1.4.4/mail-1.4.4.jar" />
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/activation.jar"
        src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar" />
</target>


<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY_US" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" locale="en,IL" />
</tstamp>
<copy todir="T:/Ali/backup/reports/AutoAccess_337/${TODAY_US}">
    <fileset dir="log/current" />
</copy>




<target name="notify" description="notify team">
    <mail mailhost="SRVSMTP" subject="latest deployment">
        <from address="ali.t@ab.com" />
        <to address="ali.t@ab.coml" />
        <message>A new build has been pushed out to prod</message>
    </mail>
</target>
```

for some reason Mail is not sent, with no any error message, 
any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried debug the ant script?

Comment: What is the output of `ant -verbose`?

Comment: [mail] Failed to send email: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

BUILD FAILED
C:\repos\AutoAccess\autoAccessTest\build.xml:21: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
 at

Comment: @ALiAuto Take a look at: [Getting error message "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage" while executing ant mail task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302832/getting-error-message-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-mail-internet-mim)

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the problem deeply: 
I added two jar files into ant lib directory, in my case and because I'm executing ant from eclipse, I checked ant home value by navigate to: (Window >> Preferences >> Ant >> RunTime >> Classpath >> Ant Home Entries).
After that I added mail.jar and Activation.jar files to lib directory under Ant home directory.
this fixed the issue.

Br,
Ali